# Javascript alert box not working

Tags: jquery, html

The following program is supposed to pop-up an alert box on clicking on "First" when it runs in the browser

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
       <meta charset="utf-8"/>

       <script src="attach.js"> </script>  
</head>

<body> 
     <div id="wrap">
              <p id="1a"> First </p>
              <p id="2b"> Second </p>
              <p id="3c"> Third </p>
              <p id="4d"> Fourth </p>
     </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The attach.js file is:

```
function getit()
{
      document.querySelector('#1a').onclick=fun2;
      document.write('Hi');
}

function fun2()
{
      alert('Yup!');
}

document.write('here');
window.onload=getit;
```

The output I get in chrome is:

```
here
First
Second
Third
Fourth
```

The problem is that on clicking "First", in the browser screen, there is no alert box saying 'Yo'. Another question is why we don't see 'Hi' being printed on the screen.

Comment: `Another question is why we don't see 'Hi' being printed on the screen.` because the page is already loaded. There is no place to `document.write` Also, id cannot start with number.

Comment: I'm getting an error saying that "#1a" is not a valid selector in chrome.

Comment: Changed the names to a, b, c, d (and made the change in .js file), still not getting the alert box!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your JS is that it has a '1' in the ID which needs to be escaped with the Unicode code for querySelector to work correctly. Also you need to remove the **document.write('Hi')** as it will overwrite your HTML

Try this

```
function getit() {
  document.querySelector('#\\31 a').onclick = fun2
}
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ShUF3LzguShG4OlzrWQZ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

About the only thing I changed was the name of 1a to aTest.  Worked after that.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
       <meta charset="utf-8"/>

</head>

<body> 
     <div id="wrap">
              <div id="aTest" class="1a"> First </div>
              <p id="2b"> Second </p>
              <p id="3c"> Third </p>
              <p id="4d"> Fourth </p>
     </div>

       <script> 
            function getit()
            {
                var a = document.querySelector('#aTest');
                a.onclick = fun2;
                //document.write('Hi');
            }

            function fun2()
            {
                  alert('Yup!');
            }

            document.write('here');
            window.onload = getit;
       </script>     
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jQuery to achieve the same result.

```
$(document).on('click','#1a',function(){
    fun2();
    console.log('hey');
})

function fun2(){
  alert('Yup!');
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that would be the better idea